# Read non-byte-aligned value from byte array

Tags: c#, byte, .net-7.0, bitarray

I am trying to read a n-bit (n <= 8) long value from a `byte[]`. This value may not be aligned to the start/end of any byte or may span two bytes. To make this more clear, please see the following example:

```cs
//                                 __     ___             ## #
var bytes = new byte[] { 0b_1111_1100, 0b_0001_1111, 0b_1100_0111 };
```

I am interested in reading the 5 zeroes spanning two bytes (marked with _) as a byte/int and the second span of 3 bits (marked with #). Obviously, the content of these bits is arbitrary, they may not all be zero.

I know that I could read the content of these bytes and calculate the value of these bits alone from there, but this seems very cumbersome to me, as it requires a lot of work to simply read some bits. The following snippet is a naive implementation of this approach:

```cs
var bytes = new byte[] { 0b_1111_1100, 0b_0001_1111, 0b_1100_0111 };
Console.WriteLine("5bit value: " + GetNBitsFromByteArray(bytes, 0, 6, 5));
Console.WriteLine("3bit value: " + GetNBitsFromByteArray(bytes, 2, 2, 3));

int GetNBitsFromByteArray(byte[] bytes, int startByte, int startBit, int length)
{
    if (startBit + length <= 8)
    {
        // The entire value is in one byte
        return GetBitsFromByte(bytes[startByte], startBit, length);
    }
    else
    {
        // The value is split over two bytes
        var lengthInByte1 = 8 - startBit;
        var part1 = GetBitsFromByte(bytes[startByte], startBit, lengthInByte1);
        var part2 = GetBitsFromByte(bytes[startByte + 1], 0, length - lengthInByte1);
        return (part1 << lengthInByte1) + part2;
    }
}

// startBit is the index of the bit where the selection should start.
// 0 is the highest bit, 7 is the lowest bit. e.g. GetBitsFromByte(0b_0001_1110, 3, 4) == 15
int GetBitsFromByte(byte byteValue, int startBit, int length)
{
    var mask = (1 << 8 - startBit) - (1 << 8 - startBit - length);
    return byteValue & mask;
}
```

Another approach is to utilise the `BitArray` class. This type does not seem to provide methods  to do the actions described above either and adding the bits (see example) does not seem very elegant either:

```cs
BitArray bits = new(new byte[] { 0b_1111_1100, 0b_0001_1111, 0b_1100_0111 });
Console.WriteLine("First ones: " + Get5BitValue(bits, 6));
Console.WriteLine("Second ones: " + Get3BitValue(bits, 18));

int Get5BitValue(BitArray bits, int startBitIndex)
{
    return (bits[startBitIndex + 0] ? 16 : 0) +
           (bits[startBitIndex + 1] ? 8 : 0) +
           (bits[startBitIndex + 2] ? 4 : 0) +
           (bits[startBitIndex + 3] ? 2 : 0) +
           (bits[startBitIndex + 4] ? 1 : 0);
}
int Get3BitValue(BitArray bits, int startBitIndex)
{
    return (bits[startBitIndex + 0] ? 4 : 0) +
           (bits[startBitIndex + 1] ? 2 : 0) +
           (bits[startBitIndex + 2] ? 1 : 0);
}
```

I know I could use something like `GetNBitValue(BitArray bits, int startBitIndex, int n)` using a loop, but to improve legibility I have chosen to include this example.

Is there any more elegant or performant approach?

PS: all code is written and tested in dotnet-7.

Comment: You could take your higher byte and shift it left by 8 bits, then OR it with the lower byte: `long twoBytes = bytes[0] << 8 | bytes[1]`.  Then use your `GetBitsFromByte` method (change the first argument to long).

Comment: @MikeH Thank you for this solution, I just tried it and it seems to be more performant, but I am still interested in whether there is some kind of dotnet method doing some 'magic' to accomplish this.

Comment: If you allow `System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86` then you could use `Bmi.BitFieldExtract` to do the extraction within the 16-bit block that you have created as MikeH showed

Comment: What you need is a `BitStream` class with `GetBit`, `GetInt(int bits)` methods.